# How to make a Java object of generic type, in Clojure?

Tags: clojure, javaparser

Clojure `empty` changes types of Java collections.
For example a `JavaParser` `MethodCallExpr` object `mce`,

```clj
(type (.getArguments mce))
;; => com.github.javaparser.ast.NodeList
(type (emtpy (.getArguments mce)))
;; => nil
(type (into (empty (.getArguments mce)) (.getArguments mce)))
;; => clojure.lang.PersistentList
```

But `(.setArguments mce ???)` needs `???` to be a `NodeList<Expression>`, so how to make an object `???` in clojure?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`empty` works only for classes that implement `clojure.lang.IPersistentCollection`. It won't work for anything else.

In your case, if you know that the type is `NodeList`, just construct it yourself via Java interop.
If you don't know that it's `NodeList` in some general case, you're out of luck because you can't construct an instance of an arbitrary class based on a single assumption that it's a collection class.